# Environment specific migrations cause issues with copying a database to different environments

Tags: migration, flyway

We've made use of environment specific migrations for things like seeding data, data correction, applying table grants.  There are times when we'd like to take a copy of production, for example, and import it to another lower environment, either as a periodic refresh, or to start a new test environment.  However, as expected, we end up with various failures like `Detected applied migration not resolved locally` and `Detected resolved migration not applied to database`.  I see there are various flags (ignoreIgnoredMigrations, ignoreMissingMigrations and outOfOrder) to allow us to bypass these issues.

Are there best practices for handling scenarios like I described?  Is there a way to run an environment specific migration that doesn't file an entry in the flyway_schema_history table?  Other approaches to this issue that I haven't mentioned?

Thanks in advance for any insights.

We have used ignoreMissingMigrations as one approach around this issue.

Comment: Would removing the schema history table and rebaselining help?

Comment: @David I think what you are suggesting is that in a new environment we could delete the schema history table and use the baseline command to recreate the history table at V1. Based on your suggestion I came across this feature https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/baselinemigrations.html which seems like another option, where periodic new baseline scripts would help alleviate the issue.  Thanks for the feedback!  Other ideas still welcomed.

Comment: Yes, but to use baseline migrations you'll need a way to create a script to cover that version range, although if you need to rebuild environments from migrations you'll need something like that.